# Cannot read property on Object (undefined?) inside instance

Tags: javascript

When i try to access the object **this.guy** from the event function **onMouveMove** i get the following error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop1' of undefined"
```

When i inspect with Chrome's Devtool, the value exist and is there, it just doesn't recognize inside the "onMouseMove" function.

```js
MyClass = function(some_html_element){
  this.guy = {"prop1":[]};
  some_html_element.onmousemove = this.onMouseMove;
}
    
MyClass.prototype.onMouseMove = function(evt){
  if(!this.guy.prop1){    //<- here's the error
            alert("no error");
  }
}

a = new MyClass(document.querySelector("#example"))
```

```html
<div id="example">
MOVE MOUSE ON ME
</div>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set the onMouseMove handler for some_html_element the function is not bound to your MyClass instance.  You can fix this by explicitly binding it:

```
MyClass = function(some_html_element){
  this.guy = {"prop1":[]};
  some_html_element.onmousemove = this.onMouseMove.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: You should mark it as a duplicate, there are already plenty of questions exactly like this

Comment: wtf, i hate javascript now.

Thanks!

Comment: @Notaprivilegeduser Don't hate.  The way JavaScript binds (or doesn't bind) functions is actually really powerful once you get a handle on it.